# Laravel eloquent pivot passing variable to model

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, model, eloquent

I have problem with pass variable to my eloquent model.I will give you example
Database :

Book :

-id

-name

User :

-id

-name

Wish-list:

-book_id

-user_id

Now when I get record of book. I whant to cheack if user have this book in wish-list.

i have relation like this :

Book eloquent model :

```
public function wishList($userId)
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Model\Pivot\WishList', 'comics_record_id')->where('user_id',$userId);
}
```

but when i run this code give me nothink.

Book Controller :

```
$record = Book:find(1);

$record->wishList(1);
```

i try also make setters in eloquent model.
nothink work :(

Thx for help and sorry for my english.

Comment: do you have any model name `WishList`??

Comment: Yes it in relation "App\Model\Pivot\WishList"
    
   protected $table='wish_list';
    protected $fillable=['book_id','user_id'];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First Change your relationship to this-

```
public function wishList()
{
return $this->hasMany('App\Model\Pivot\WishList', 'book_id', 'id');
}
```

And then your relationship would be-

```
$book = Book::with('wishList')->where('id',$book_id)->whereHas('wishList', function($q) use ($user_id){
       $q->where('user_id',$user_id);
})->first();

if($book){
    //show true here
}
else{
    //show false here
 }
```

Comment: I could work but what when i will try to get collection. 
i want to achieve something like 
{
 name: book_name, 
 wishlist : true  ( Or null,false if isn’t  in his list. ) 
} I need books not only from his list :(

Comment: I made something like this : 

$user_id=2;
$book=Book::find(1);
$book->whereDoesntHave('wishList', function($q) use ($user_id){
            $q->where('user_id',$user_id);
        });
return $book;

but unfortunately still don't get relation in result.

Comment: what do you want?? Do you want the book list that a user is not made whish list?? Or just want to check for a particular book is whishlisted by a user or not?

Comment: I want get list of books like 200 records or more.
And for each record I want to check if user have this book in wish-list or not.
its 2 steps user login into application 
then go to list of books And next to book title he have mark if he have this in wish-list or not.

Comment: It's should work but I didn't get any field wish-list in result.
When I try this function or other this field just disappear.
I think I had to make raw  query or get list user book's from wish_list and make some statements .

Comment: see now, you will have wishlist

Comment: This is close one ! its work on single record thx for that :D 
but now I have to use it on collection.

$records=Book::all();
foreach($book as $item){
$item->model->with('wishList')->whereHas('wishList', function($q) use ($user_id){
                $q->where('user_id',$user_id);
            });
}

you have any idea how can I use it in collections ?

Comment: `Book::with('wishList')->where('id',$item->id)->whereHas('wishList', function($q) use ($user_id){
       $q->where('user_id',$user_id);
})->first();`

Comment: Yea but its for single record now i need to use it on many record :(

 $records=Book::all();
 foreach($book as $item){ 
$item->with('wishList')->whereHas('wishList', function($q) use ($user_id){ $q->where('user_id',$user_id); });
$item->othersRelations;
 }

Comment: `if($item->wis‌​hList()->where('user_id',$user_id)->first()) then true else false`

Comment: $model->wishList->where('user_id',1); and its worked :D THX a lot you are my personal hero

Answer (score 0):

First of all you are passing $userId and in where clause you are using $userID .... undefined variable error here.

Comment: sry i corrected this.But still that not the problem